# How may I achieve this splitting logic using hibernate or sql or java or using any other way

Tags: javascript, java, sql, hibernate

I have **TableA** which has **two columns** with data **1,50**(ie 1,2,3....50) respectively & i have **TableB** which Contains same **two columns** but with data **20,30**(ie 20,21.....30) & **40,45** (40,41....45)respectively and i want to find out **remaining set of series** as output in **TableC Like entries** **1,19 & 31,39** &**46,49**. How Can i Achieve this using hibernate ,mysql,or simply java.  [please refer this snap for database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1ZMq.png)

Comment: I understand nothing.

Comment: This is extremely unclear.  It'd probably be easier to understand if you posted the exact data and structures of the tables and clearly indicate what data you're trying to obtain.

Comment: @degr please do refer a link shared by me above. Thanks in advance

Comment: @tilper please do refer link above for my database structure